# Off-line to-do list, alternative to Trello/Kanboard

Tags: windows, offline, ubuntu, time-management

People like connecting everything to the internet. I know, because it's part of my job description.

However, one of my devices (it's a laptop/tablet hybrid) is never connected to the internet. This is by design. Now I'm looking for a to-do application along the lines of [Trello](https://trello.com/)/[Kanboard](http://kanboard.net/). Kanboard can be run off-line if you run it locally. However, this feels an awful lot like cutting cardboard with a hammer.

I need something extensive. Open-source would be great (one of the pros is it leaves room for modifications), but anything else would also work.

- Internet connectivity must never be required.
- Extensive.
- Run on either Ubuntu or Windows 8.1
- Modifiability is a pre.

Comment: I use a time tracking tool (Project Hamster) as my To-Do-List thing. But as I was primarily looking for and using it as time tracker I'm not so good at vetting if it would suit your need. Its in the Ubuntu software repository iirc. If you try it and it works drop a line :) https://github.com/projecthamster/hamster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Task Coach](http://www.taskcoach.org/)

Task Coach is an open-source to-do list manager written in Python. Its features include:

- Works offline
- "Extensive" is a broad term, so [here's a full list of features](http://www.taskcoach.org/features.html)
- Cross-platform: runs on **both** Ubuntu and Windows. Also has a [PortableApps version](http://portableapps.com/apps/office/task_coach_portable) for installation on a USB stick
- It's modifiable if you know Python. You can download the sources [here](http://www.taskcoach.org/download_sources.html)

Comment: First impression is it definitely fits the bill. Good suggestion!

Comment: I know Task Coach, but that's quite different from Trello/Kanboard, it doesn't have boards, which are fundamental to the Kanban method (see [Kanban board](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanban_board))

Comment: @mguassa Thanks. I was not familiar with the Kanban method, and it's true that Task Coach doesn't follow it. However, it was not an explicit requirement in the question. I'll delete the answer if the OP deems it unfit

Comment: @mguassa I think something weird happened here. The answer isn't an exact match with the question for the reason you stated. However, it definitely fits my need. So, without stating the right question, the right answer came along anyway :-)

Comment: @Mast The thing is, I'd still like to know a good offline alternative to Trello/Kanboard...

Comment: @mguassa I think your two best options here are 1) a follow-up question with stricter requirements, or 2) waiting a few days for more answers on this one, then posting a bounty with your requirement as the condition